# ブランクテーマ「naked Wordpress」使用時のコメントフォームのカスタマイズについて

Tags: wordpress

ブランクテーマ「naked Wordpress」使用時のコメントフォームのカスタマイズを試みているのですが、全くうまくいきません。
私の技量ではWebで調べたコードだけでは太刀打ちでできませんでした。

naked Wordpressを使用されており、コメントフォームのカスタマイズ方法を御存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら下記についてご教示いただきたいです。

『コメントフォームの文面（コメントフォームのタイトル、お名前（必須）、メールアドレス、URLといったテキストの箇所）を変更、削除する方法』

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

試しにインストールしてみました（VCCWを使用しました）。
以下、「コメントフォーム = Leave a Reply と書いてある所」という前提での記載です。
※違う場所の話でしたらすみません。

「naked Wordpress」ではなく「wordpress」の以下の場所に該当ファイル（comments.php）があります。

wordpress -> wp-includes -> theme-compat -> comments.php

L.68 辺りにタイトル（Leave a Reply)
L.86 辺りから入力項目（Name, Mail, Website）

があります（`<?php else : ?>`とか書いてあるので条件によって変わるかもしれません）。

補足として、今回は下記コマンドで wordpress 配下を検索しました。

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' | xargs grep '(required)'
```

Answer (score -1):

投稿者です。
コメントありがとうございます。
wp-includes内の
comment-template.php
comment.php
この2つばかりを気にしていました。

こちらについては全く気づいておりませんでした…。
wp-includes -> theme-compat -> comments.php

テーマ自体にcomment.phpがあることが多く、wp-includes内を触ることがあまりなかったので、
良いヒントになりました。

またコマンドのご紹介ありがとうございます。
こちらも様々な場面で利用できそうで大変助かりました。

実際に作業を行いましたら改めて経過報告させていただきます。

以下補足になります。
質問投稿後に思い切ってテーマ自体を変更してみました。
テーマ自体にcomment.phpがあるBlank theme「Underscores」を利用しました。
このケースですとWeb検索で参考になる情報が多くあるので、比較的カスタマイズしやすかったです。
なお、コメントフォームの言語表記を変更するには「poedit」の力を借りる必要がありました。
（スクリプトを触るだけでは細かな文言のカスタマイズは完遂できませんでした）

Answer (score -1):

頂いたコメントを元にWordpressを編集してみました。
 wp-includes -> theme-compat -> comments.php

L.68 以降の編集でカスタマイズができることを確認しました。

オリジナルスクリプトを以下のように変えることでコメント見出しの文章を「テスト文章」に編集できます。

```
<h3><?php comment_form_title( __('テスト文章'), __('Leave a Reply to %s' ) ); ?></h3>
```

Leave a Reply to の箇所も同様に編集できます。
またh3の中身をまるっと削除でコメントの見出しを消すこともできます。

この箇所をダイレクトに編集するか、function.phpからアクションフックを利用して調整を入れることでコメント欄のカスタマイズができるようです。

コメントでヒントをくださった方ありがとうございました。